# ¿Alguien conoce el Voyager de Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, select, laravel-blade

Tengo un problema que no consigo solucionar, ¿alguien conoce de Laravel un ADMIN que se llama Voyager?

Tengo problemas con las relaciones a la hora de editar form, que me devuelve error y por mucho que he leído en ingles a mucha gente le pasa pero no encuentro solución.

El error.

> ```
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'idEstado' 
> cannot be null (SQL: update `Vivienda` set `idEstado` = , `updated_at` 
> = 2018-12-21 20:54:39 where `idVivienda` = 2)
> ```

Más del error:

> ```
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'idEstado' 
> cannot be null (23000)
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'idEstado' 
> cannot be null (23000)
> ```

Código.

```
 catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new QueryException(
            $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
        );
    }

    return $result;
```

No puedo poner más código, esto se hace todo a través de ese panel de administración.

Pueden ver esta página:

https://docs.laravelvoyager.com/core-concepts/bread-builder#relationships

Devuelve null, pero se supone que en la relación le pido que inserte el id aunque saque el nombre.

Gracias.

Comment: si agregas el error, por ahi podemos empezar

Comment: @shadow ya he puesto el error

Comment: Ademas del error agrega el código donde obtienes el error

Comment: @shadow listo! ya lo tienes

Comment: Parece más un bug de Voyager, yo lo reportaría en el Github de ellos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Shaz

Answer (score 0):

Checa que en la clase encargada de hacer el insert o update tengas dentro de fillable el campo idEstado para que pueda ser editado.

Deberia verse algo asi:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class NombreDeTuClase extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'idEstado',
        'otroCampo',
        'otroCampo2',       
    ];
}
```