# Insertar en la BD después de envio email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Buenas soy nuevo en Laravel, y hay cosas que ya sabia hacer pero con Laravel se me hace un mundo.

Tengo un formulario de llámame ahora y mi interés es que después de enviar el email, esos datos quiero meterlos en BD, alguna ayuda?

**Controlador:** *(Dentro de este mismo tengo más funciones para los distintos formularios)*

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\Mail\Contactanos;
 use App\Mail\Tasacion;
 use App\Mail\Llamanos;
 use App\Mail\vende;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

 class CorreoController extends Controller
 {

 public function correoLlamanos(Request $request)
 {
  Mail::to(env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'))->send(new Llamanos($request->telefono));
  flash()->overlay('Su mensaje a sido enviado con exitó, pronto le llamaran', 'Mensaje enviado!!');
  return redirect()->route('inicio');
}
```

**La aplicación MAIL:**

```
namespace App\Mail;

 use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
 use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
 use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

 class Llamanos extends Mailable
 {
 use Queueable, SerializesModels;

 public $telefono;

  /**
  * Create a new message instance.
  *
  * @return void
  */
 public function __construct($telefono = '')
 {
  $this->telefono = $telefono;
 }

 /**
  * Build the message.
  *
  * @return $this
  */
 public function build()
 {
    return $this->from(env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'))
            ->view('emails.llamanos');
 }

 }
```

**Route:**

```
 Route::post('llamanos', 'CorreoController@correoLlamanos')->name('correo.llamanos');
```

**La vista mail**

```
 <h1>Has recibido una petición de llamada</h1>

 <b>Teléfono:</b> {{ $telefono }}
```

Comment: ¿qué es Llamada entonces?

Comment: El nombre de la BD @Shaz

Comment: Me refiero a esta clase `$llamada = new Llamada;`, ¿qué contiene?

Comment: Entiendo que significa, nuevo registro en la tabla Llamada.... sorry si digo una tonteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podría utilizarse el Query Builder para guardar la información, en caso que sea algo muy básico:

```
public function almacenarLlamadas(Request $request)
{
    DB::table('calls')->insert(
        ['phone_number' => $request->telefono]
    );
}
```

Sin embargo, si se necesita interactuar con otros modelos, o si se necesita jugar con el formato de la información, entre tantas otras cosas que puede hacer un modelo en Laravel y Eloquent, entonces si sería una buena idea utilizar modelos.

Más información sobre el Query Builder en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#inserts

---

Basado en la edición de la pregunta, modifico el código del método en mención:

```
public function correoLlamanos(Request $request)
{

    DB::table('calls')->insert(
        ['phone_number' => $request->telefono]
    );

    Mail::to(env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'))->send(new Llamanos($request->telefono));
    flash()->overlay('Su mensaje a sido enviado con exitó, pronto le llamaran', 'Mensaje enviado!!');
    return redirect()->route('inicio');
}
```

Se debe incluir el facade DB también:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Mail\{Contactanos, Tasacion, Llamanos, vende};
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\{DB, Mail};

...
```

Comment: Una pregunta, pero tengo varios formularios, como entiende laravel que tiene que coger justo ese dato que yo quiero? Esto lo pongo en el controlador? Gracias @Shaz

Comment: ¿cuál dato? Todo depende de como organices la lógica de la aplicación, asumo que el método ya lo tienes en el controlador actualmente.

Comment: Si pero al ser varios formularios en la aplicación no se como entiende laravel que justo quiero ese dato "telefono"

Comment: No me hace nada @Shaz

Comment: Creo que no entiendes muy bien como funcina Laravel, si quieres que te ayudemos mejor, debes proporcionar información completa y mostrar mensajes de error. Te recomiendo además que te documentes mejor sobre Laravel.

Comment: Si soy totalmente nuevo en Laravel @Shaz si quieres muestro como envio el mail y vemos donde se deberia de realizar el insert. Voy a editar la pregunta...

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega la información necesaria para que entendamos el problema y para que entiendas la solución, la cual te aseguro que funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Ya modifique la pregunta con todo lo que tengo @Shaz...

Comment: Ya edité la respuesta, claramente debes reemplazar `calls` y `phone_number` por los nombres de la tabla y campo de la base de datos.

Comment: De devuelve este error! @Shaz <br> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `Llamada` (`telefono`) values (987098765))

Comment: No le hagas caso, simplemente no estaba en primario, simplemente funciona perfecto, que facilidad esto de Laravel cuando sabes como hacerlo, muchas gracias

Comment: Hecho!!! Una pregunta entiendes algo del panel de administración que se llama Voyager de laravel? @Shaz ??

Comment: Visita esto porfa que ya lo publique @Shaz https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225085/alguien-conoce-de-laravel-el-voyager?noredirect=1#comment418109_225085

Comment: Perdona @shaz si fuera más de una columna que tengo que insertar,  ['phone_number' => $request->telefono];  ['estado' => $request->estado]; ---- Que se separa por ";" o "," o otra cosa?

Comment: Es un array: `['phone_number' => $request->telefono, 'estado' => $request->estado]`

Comment: Gracias, funciona perfecto @Shaz